# Find all the properties for an object

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

Im new to VB and have been thrown into using a massive web service. I am constantly receiving back objects and it would be very useful be able to print out all of their properties. Is there a way in VB to get all the properties of an object and print them out (to console)?

Im thinking this would need some type of reflection, but it would be nice if there was some kind of built in mechanism for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Read your question again and got a little more enlightened :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332493(v=vs.71).aspx

You can use this to get the properties of an object:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim myType As Type = GetType(MyTypeClass)
    ' Get the public properties.
    Dim myPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo() = myType.GetProperties((BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance))
    Console.WriteLine("The number of public properties is {0}.", myPropertyInfo.Length.ToString())
    ' Display the public properties.
    DisplayPropertyInfo(myPropertyInfo)
End Sub 'Main

Public Shared Sub DisplayPropertyInfo(ByVal myPropertyInfo() As PropertyInfo)
        ' Display the information for all properties.
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To myPropertyInfo.Length - 1
            Dim myPropInfo As PropertyInfo = CType(myPropertyInfo(i), PropertyInfo)
            Console.WriteLine("The property name is {0}.", myPropInfo.Name.ToString())
            Console.WriteLine("The property type is {0}.", myPropInfo.PropertyType.ToString())
        Next i
    End Sub 'DisplayPropertyInfo
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Suppose I didn't know any of the names of the properties until runtime though. Any idea how to get the property names?

Comment: Changed response to reflect your question's nature.

Comment: Ok cool. So now I've got the name. Can I use this name and get the value of the property? Something like GetProeprtyValue(PropertyName)

Comment: I'll answer this when I get home :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not good enough at VB to show you. I know how to do it in C# though but that will hardly help you or answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx)
This returns an array with PropertyInfo object which each represent a property on your object. The PropertyInfo object has a [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx) object which holds the name of the property on your object.

Answer (score 0):

In a SOA world you can achieve that with the WSDL (WSDL Types)

you can find all the information you need as the nature of the service in generals states that they must be self contained and auto descriptive

for more info:

http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_documents.asp